# Uploading image to S3 using AWS AppSync on IOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, graphql, aws-appsync

I am following [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-ios.html) to upload a file to `S3` through `AppSync` from my IOS client, in which I am told to include the `local uri` when creating a `S3Object` as part of my mutation request. However, what if I have the image `Data` and want to work with that directly instead?

I know I can upload `Data` to S3 using `TransferUtility`, how can I achieve the same goal through AppSync directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, AppSync only supports the upload of a file to S3 and doesn't offer the capability of uploading a data object directly. I will work with the AppSync team to get this into their queue as a feature request.